# Responsive design below 600px causing problems for navbar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm currently creating media queries for my current project, the problem I'm currently facing is that something is causing my navbar to not be responsive below width of 600px. What happens is show in the attached image.

[image: What happens]

I've actually solved this problem once before in a previous project but can't remember how I solved this problem even after comparing the code.

[image: What I want to happen]

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav-bar">
            <span class="open-slide">
                <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </span>
            <ul class="nav-items">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#order">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section id="about">
            <div class="about-text">
                <h1>Comics.Cards.Fun</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, neque ipsa nisi voluptatum distinctio asperiores dolorem obcaecati reiciendis sunt eaque veritatis omnis, rerum qui aperiam totam magnam sit facilis quod.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="events">
            <h1>Events</h1>
            <div class="cards-container">
                <% Event.all.each do |event|%>
                    <div class="event-card">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="event-date">
                            <span class="date"><%= event.date %></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="event-image">
                            <%= image_tag event.image_url.to_s %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="event-data">
                            <div class="event-title">
                                <h3><%= event.title %></h3>
                            </div>
                            <p class="event-details"><%= event.description %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="order">
            <h1>Order</h1>
            <p>Looking for your monthly fix of comics? Just order from us!</p>
            <div class="order-steps">
                <div class="fill-form">
                    <i class="far fa-list-alt fa-10x"></i>
                    <p>
                        List down all the comics you wish to order.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="email-us">
                    <i class="far fa-envelope fa-10x"></i>
                    <p>
                        Email it to us at the 
                        <br> 
                        lastcomicshop@gmail.com
                        <br>
                        Deadline is the 20<sup>th</sup> of every month
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="delivery">
                    <i class="fas fa-truck fa-10x"></i>
                    <p>
                        If you wish to have your comics delivered, just give us your address!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="locations">
            <h1>Locations</h1>
            <div class="location-div">
                <div class="google-maps">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3983.8821426536624!2d101.61402541462657!3d3.1258517541674418!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cc49cb25b5c01b%3A0xfcdf88c63a471fd6!2sThe+Last+Comic+Shop!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smy!4v1554862822510!5m2!1sen!2smy" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="address">
                    <p>
                        75A, Jalan SS22/23,
                        <br>
                        Damansara Utama,
                        <br>
                        47400 Petaling Jaya, Selangor
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="contact-us">
            <p>Connect with us:</p>
            <div class="contact-outlets">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                <i class="far fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
// Place all the styles related to the Home controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

// Navbar
.nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: white;
}

.nav-bar > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-bar > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.nav-bar > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-size: 21px;
}

// Sections
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
        font-size: 53px;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 26px;
    }
}

#about {
    background-color: rgba(243, 63, 63, 0.8);

    .about-text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 45%;
    }
}

#events {
    background-color: rgba(63, 63, 243, 0.8);

    .cards-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
}

#order {
    background-color: rgb(25, 134, 25);

    .order-steps {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;

        .fill-form,
        .email-us,
        .delivery {
            width: 20%;

            i {
                padding-bottom: 1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}

#locations {
    background-color: rgb(245, 233, 63);

    .location-div {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

#contact-us {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;

    p {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .contact-outlets {
        width: 125px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
// Event cards
.event-card {
    width: 30%;
    height: 58%;
    position: relative;
    // background: url(https://idigitalcitizen.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/6x4-autobobots-logo.jpg) 50% / cover no-repeat;
    margin: 0 1.3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .event-date {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0.8rem;
        background-color: #77d7b9;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        .date {
            font-size: 24px;
            text-shadow: 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
        }

        .month {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .month,
        .year {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .event-image {
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
        }
    }

    .event-data {
        width: 100%;
        height: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        padding: 0.8rem 0.5rem;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        // Takes the height of the h3 tag with the class event-title and adds 3.5rem to hide the event details.
        transform: translateY(calc(145px + 0.5rem));
        transition: transform 0.5s;

        .event-title {
            font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        .event-details {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    // When user hovers their mouse over the card, the event details pop up.
    &:hover {
        .overlay {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 0.5;
            transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s, ease;
        }
        .event-data {
            transform: translateY(0);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }
    }
}

// Responsive design

// Extra Small & Small devices
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    // navbar
    .nav-bar {
        ul {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is Iframe width

Comment: you mean the content or the navbar button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set your navbar to 100% width (which is fine), but since your iframe's width is **600px** it allows your navbar to stretch all the way to reach this "100%" width. Change your iframe width to the page's width so your navbar and your page won't go off-boundary. Like this:

`<iframe src="..." width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

Once that's done, I'd recommend reducing the nav items' font-size to have them all fit on your nav bar.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Bareket!! That solved the problem